# Linking JS/jQuery to WordPress functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Following a tutorial that recommends the following code to link JS/jQuery to WordPress, within functions.php:

```
<?php 

function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js' ) );
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );

?>
```

But something is wrong, either the jQuery or the bootstrap.min.js did not link properly, possibly both. How can I ensure that both are linked?

Comment: find link of your js in your page source code from browser and click on it and if its showing code then your script is linked.

Comment: By default, WordPress bundles many popular scripts commonly used, and **jquery** is one of them... 

so replace "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" this with "jquery"

then it should work...

Comment: Here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/1103/enqueuing-scripts#t=201610080706239319699 And for a safe measure: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/1247/enqueuing-styles#t=201610080706359289692

Comment: Thanks guys! Linked and functional now!